# Why would the use of static const in second class give compiler error in first class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, static, constants

In a single header file, I have 2 class declaration. And one of them contains const value that I would like to use on top declared class.

Following is the basic implementation.

```
class B;
class A
{
public :
    friend class B; // this should not matter since CONST_VAL is public
    int a;
    A() { a = B::CONST_VAL; } // !!! error line
}
class B
{
public :
    static const int CONST_VAL = 1;
}
```

I feel this should be very basic concept, but I am getting compiler error. `error C2027 : use of undefined type 'B'` as well as `error 2065: 'CONST_VAL': undeclared identifier`

Why would this constructor think it does not know B nor B::CONST_VAL?

Comment: Because at this point `A() { a = B::CONST_VAL; } `, the compiler has not seen `static const int CONST_VAL = 1;`. Or indeed the definition of `B`.

Comment: You are using a forward declaration. B is not defined yet when you try to use it. Get rid of the forward declaration and define B before A. Also consider one class per file.

Comment: Yes indeed Forward declaration is used so second error may make more sense. However, wouldn't the compiler at least know type 'B'?

Comment: It knows it is a type, but that's all.

Comment: @ShintaroTakechi the message says "use of undefined type B". B has been declared but not defined,   it is literally undefined at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you've given, `B` is forward declared at the top of the file:

```
class B;
...
```

This tells the compiler that `B` *exists* as a class, but the compiler doesn't know anything about `B` because its definition hasn't yet appeared. With a forward declaration like this, it doesn't make sense to use any `B` objects or members. You're allowed to use `B*` pointers because they don't require any implementation details of `B` however.

To fix this, you need to provide the definition of `B` before it's needed, either at the top of the file, or in a separate header file that you `#include`. For example:

```
class B {
public :
    static const int CONST_VAL = 1;
};

class A {
public :
    int a;
    A() : a(B::CONST_VAL) { }
}
```